# node js async writting from variable which is randomly updating like wifi networks

Tags: node.js, http, server, wifi

I am trying to display the wifi networks around me on the web page.
But due to the asynchronous nature of node js. I am getting the value undefined as it is returning the value before the scanning is completed.

I am using 
1. node 'wireless-tools' package
2. http server module which came by default in node js.

here is my code:

```
function scan() {
iwlist.scan({
        iface : 'wlp1s0',
        show_hidden : true
    },
    function(err, networks) {
        return networks;
    }
    });
}

const http = require('http');

const hport = 8080;
const haddr = "localhost";
const Server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    var n = scan();
    res.write(n);
    res.end();
});
Server.listen(hport, haddr, () => {
console.log('Server running at ' + haddr + ' ' + hport);
```

});

It is displaying me undefined on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use async/await to work with it.I had not tested the code.Please check the code.

```
function scan() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            iwlist.scan({
                iface: 'wlp1s0',
                show_hidden: true
            },
                function (err, networks) {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    return resolve(networks);
                }
            );
        });

    }

    const http = require('http');

    const hport = 8080;
    const haddr = "localhost";
    const Server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
        try {
            var n = await scan();
            res.write(n);
            res.end();
        }
        catch (error) {
            res.write(error);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are affecting the immediate return value of `iwlist.scan()` into the `n` variable. This function uses a classic nodejs callback to handle the asynchronous behavior, so it might always return undefined, as the result will go into the callback.

Two solutions:

1) Affect your variable result inside the callback

```
function scan(myCallback) {
   iwlist.scan({
      iface : 'wlp1s0',
      show_hidden : true
   }, myCallback);
});

const Server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
   var n;
   scan(function(error, result) {
      n = result;
      res.write(n);
      res.end();
   });
});
```

2) You transform the existing function into a promise using [Promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

```
var scanAsync = utils.promisify(iwlist.scan)
function async scan() {
   // Will return the result as a promise
   return scanAsync({
      iface : 'wlp1s0',
      show_hidden : true
   });
};

try {
   var n = await scan();
} catch (e) {
   // Handle error
}
```